# Loop is not geting exited in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple progrm in Python but when my number is getting equal to number the else statement keeps repeating itself. Help

```
print('Tell me your name Ramesh')
import random
name=input()
print('Howdy, '+name)
print('Guess my number which is in between 1 to 20')
number=input()
mynumber = random.randint(1, 20)
count = 0
while(mynumber!=number):
    if (int(number) > mynumber):
        print('Howdy, Your number is too high. Plz renter')
        number=input()
        count=count+1
    elif (int(number)< mynumber):
        print('Howdy, Your number is too low. Plz renter')
        number=input()
        count=count+1
    else :
        print('Howdy you got it in '+ str(count)+' chances. The correct number is '+number)
```

Comment: Use `number = int(input())` and there is no need to convert it later in the code ... or to forget it as you did here: `while(mynumber!=number):`. BTW, get rid of the parens, `while mynumber != number:` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've only just started python myself and had the same issue.

Your if statements all convert the entered number to an int however your while doesn't. so it's comparing an int and string. Try:

```
while(mynumber != int(number))
```

or change the input to read

```
number = int(input("blah")).
```

I like this more even though it will throw an error if you enter text.

Comment: i got it. I shouldnt have used else part inside because it was while was checking the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to change the while to read while(mynumber != int(number)) as well as adding in the break within the ELSE. You could also remove the else and just let the loop fall out if the numbers match and then show the success message.